# Unable to install update-notifier-common on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, dependencies, debian, apt-get, debian-stretch

I'm currently trying to install some fonts on Debian Stretch

```
g@i-3-nstance:~$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer : Depends: update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
g@i-3-nstance:~$
```

...but it seems this package has been removed.

https://github.com/plone/ansible-playbook/issues/98

https://github.com/jnv/ansible-role-unattended-upgrades/issues/6#issuecomment-93569818

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [How do I find packages to install via apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/q/4477).

Comment: @jww You really don't have anything better to do?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I did a manual install based on this: https://askubuntu.com/a/861476

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract libmspack0
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer in spite of someone downvote this. It really helped me resolve the problem while Docker build. In my case, the problem occurs after update PHP container `php:7.3-fpm-stretch` to `php:7.4-fpm-buster`.

Answer (score -1):

The `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package that `apt-get` tries to install is from Ubuntu repository, not from Debian repository (note that it depends on update-notifier-common >= 0.119**ubuntu2**).

You probably have mixed Debian and Ubuntu repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.